# laravel whereJson Contains on laravel audits

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-auditing

In new values column for `auditable_id=2239`, `new_values` is `{"video_status_ids":"[4,10]"}` I am getting correct data for

In tinker

```
App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->get()
```

Collection contains

```
OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit {#3140
         id: 322113,
         user_type: "App\User",
         user_id: 3,
         event: "updated",
         auditable_type: "App\Video",
         auditable_id: 2239,
         old_values: "{"video_status_ids":"[4, 8]"}",
         new_values: "{"video_status_ids":"[4,10]"}",
         url: "http://example.com?",
         ip_address: "ipaddr",
         user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.
36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36",
         tags: null,
         created_at: "2019-03-04 13:30:57",
         updated_at: "2019-03-04 13:30:57",
       },
```

but for

1.`App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->whereJsonContains('new_values->video_status_ids', 10)->get()`

and

2.`App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->where('new_values->video_status_id', 10)->get()`

and

3.`App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->where('new_values->video_status_ids', "[10]")->get()`

I am getting

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#138
     all: [],
   }
```

but I should get the above records.

**Work around**

```
App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->where('new_values', 'like','\{"video_status_ids"%10%')->get()
```

and

```
App\Video::find(2239)->audits()->where('new_values->video_status_ids', 'like',"%10%")->get();
```

but if there is something like 101, 100 etc, this will not work. for only my requirement, it will be fine.

Comment: is this any solution? from https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing/issues/449

Comment: @bhavinjr If you notice that is a query builder answer and I am using eloquent here.